# How to deploy TypeScript/Node.js service with Yarn 1 and workspaces?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

I'm trying to build a Docker image for a service built using yarn workspaces inside a monorepo and I can't figure out how to get an appropriate `node_modules` inside of it. Is there any way to run `yarn install` that will create a full blown file tree structure for `node_modules`? As far as I can tell, there are two issues:

- Hoisting of common dependencies up into `node_modules` in the project root
- Symlinking of local modules in `node_modules` to their respective directories.

Is there any way to get around this?

(yarn version: 1.22.10)

Comment: Have your git repository more than one package.json? Source : https://dev.to/stepanvanzuriak/let-s-start-with-yarn-2-workspaces-32bo

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out that the (pretty obvious) answer is to run yarn install inside the docker container when it is being built. That way the service is no longer seen as being a workspace.